# How can I find how often the sum of three consecutive values in a set equal a certain value?

Tags: php, algorithm

> 9 numbers. Count how often the sum of 3 consecutive numbers in this set of numbers equaled to 16:
>       2, 7, 7, 1, 8, 2, 7, 8, 7,

The answer is 2. `2 + 7 + 7 = 16` and `7 + 1 + 8 = 16`

But I can't seem to get the answer, because I don't know how to "loop" back and skip the first number and do the process over.

How would one be able to solve this utilizing arrays, and how would one solve this without utilizing arrays?

The 9 numbers are randomly generated, and it has to stay that way, but for the sake of solving, I used seed of 3 using `srand(3)`. This is my current code below:

```
<?php
srand(3);

$count = 1;
$answer = 0;

$num1 = 0;
$num2 = 0;
$num3 = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++)
{
    $num = rand(0, 9);

    echo $num . ', ';

    if ($count == 1)
        $num1 = $num;
    else if ($count == 2)
        $num2 = $num;
    else if ($count == 3)
    {
        $num3 = $num;
        $count = 1;
    }

    if ($num1 + $num2 + $num3 == 16)
        $answer++;

    $count++;
}

echo '<br />*******' . $answer . '*******';
?>
```

Obviously this isn't the right answer because I had to do the check again, but skipping the first number, and so on and so forth until (the last indexed number - index 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a PHP writer but this could be your approach:

1. Fill the array from indices `0` up to and including `8` with a random value.
2. Iterate from index `0` to index `[length - 3]`. (`length` is `9`)
3. Calculate the sum of the values on index `[currentIndex]`, [`currentIndex + 1]` and `[currentIndex + 2]`.
4. Whenever the value of that sum equals `16`, increment your `[count]` variable by `1`.

Comment: Because you had a good general answer and because you edited my post and corrected the many grammatical mistakes I made. Question, would there be any way to do this without having to use arrays?

Comment: @JeromieDevera: yes, just create 3 numbers in each iteration and see if they total 16. That will essentially simulate taking 3 consecutive items, but I doubt that is the right answer because it makes it a lot more simple to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but its hard to think at 11 at night:

```
$array = array(2, 7, 7, 1, 8, 2, 7, 8, 7);
$count = count($array);
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    $parts = array_chunk($array, 3);
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (array_sum($part) == 16 && count($part) == 3) {
            print_r($part);
        }
    }
    array_shift($array);
}
```

Another solution which I think is the more efficient, logic similar to what @Jeroen Vannevel answered:

```
$array = array(2, 7, 7, 1, 8, 2, 7, 8, 7);
$count = count($array) - 2;

for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    if ($array[$x] + $array[$x+1] + $array[$x+2] == 16) {
        echo "{$array[$x]} + {$array[$x+1]} + {$array[$x+2]} = 16 <br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, wouldn't it be `$count = count($array) - n` with n being the amount of consecutive numbers (which in this case be 3?)

Comment: @JeromieDevera n-1, array index in PHP start at 0. Try doing a var_dump for the x, x+1, x+2 in the loop and change that 2 to a 3 and see what happens.

Comment: But doesn't `count()` start at 1? I var_dumped it and it seems to have not read in the last 3 integers.

Comment: `$count` in the above case would be 7, which means the loop would run from 0 to 6 (7 times). It will stop once it reaches the no more three numbers to add. If we kept it going it would add `8 + 7 + null`, and then `7 + null+ null`, which I assume you don't want since your requirement said three numbers.